# How to find the maclaurin expansion for an implicit trig function? $y=\sin(x+y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I'm currently creating a function for my final maths assignment, which I'm seeking to find a maclaurin expansion for. The specific function is:
$$
f(x,y)=\sin((2π/1.17)x+(π/2-1.047)y)
$$
I know that when finding the maclaurin expansion, you usually find $f(0)$ of multiple derivatives, in order to find the coefficients, but how about in this case when I have two variables: $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Do you want an answer to the question in the title, or the question in the body, or both?

Comment: A general way of tackling the problem would be ver helpful, but yes, ultimately I am seeking to find the expansion for my function.

Comment: A precise answer to clarifying questions would be helpful, too. Again: what (if any) is the connection between the title and the body of your question, and what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The connection is that my function f(x,y) is in the form of y=sin(x+y). I thought there might be a general way of expanding functions of that form, which i could then apply to expand f(x,y); and that is what i am looking for.

Comment: E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series , section *Taylor series in several variables*

Comment: No, you're mixing up two different notions: $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables, while $y=\sin(x+y)$ is an equation, defining an implicit function $y(x)$ of one variable, if that's what you mean. The latter could be expanded in a Taylor series, indeed, though you didn't say around which value. Around $x=0$ would be most convenient, because $y(0)=0$, obviously.